# ReferenceError: Parse is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I get this error with a Parse.com JS App:

> ReferenceError: Parse is not defined.

I really don't know why. Everything looks good to me. The files are linked correctly; I've checked this a few times. Is it not true, that I have to put my own JS right below Parse and it should work? This is what I've read here: [Github Project](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/AnyYolk/blob/master/index.html)
I use Chrome with the ripple extension. I serve the app via `cordova serve`

Any help much appreciated!

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <title>Zone</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="../img/site-logo.png" rel="external" class="logo">
    <!-- <div class="site-menu">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i><p class="title"></p><i></i>
    </div> -->
    <a href="#"><img src="img/suche.jpg" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/essentrinken.jpg" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/einkaufen.jpg" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/kultur.jpg" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/dienstleistungen.jpg" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/nuetzlich.jpg" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/nummern.jpg" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/sport.jpg" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/verwaltung.jpg" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/hotel.jpg" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/neuzuzuger.jpg" class="icon"></a>

    <div class="adad"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the JS file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Parse.initialize("", "");

    var Ad = Parse.Object.extend("Ads");
    function getPosts() {
        var query = new Parse.Query(Ad);
        query.find({
            success: function (results) {
                console.log("hello");
                var output = "";

                for (var i in results) {
                    var name = results[i].get("location");

                    if (name == 10) {
                        output += "<img src = '" + imageurl + "' class='media-object' height='60' width='100'>"
                    }
                }

                $("#adad").html(output);
                console.log(output);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("Query error:" + error.message);
            }
        });
    }
    getPosts();
});
```

Comment: Which js file are you showing? the ../js/main.js or the ../js/index.js file?

Comment: ../js/main.js is the file i provide here

Comment: @RobbertvandenBogerd when i work with cordova, do i have to place Parse in index.js? Doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Please try to be a bit more elaborate, i.e. what browser do you use? on which line (in which file) is the error thrown?

Comment: @RobbertvandenBogerd Sure, the Question is better now

Comment: download parse to a lib folder of your project.     <script src="../../lib/parse-1.6.7.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, I have no experience with Cordova, but in general I've seen problems like these being caused by live reloading of files or by asynchronous loading, which could be caused by cordova/gulp/nodejs.

Maybe you should use a require statement as shown on the [Parse quick start guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/web/new): `var Parse = require('parse');`

When I try your html and javascript in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sq20trs0/) it just works, so it should have something to do with the order of loading js files in your local "webserver".

Comment: I found the Solution now... There was a strange error in ripple. The App works well in Chrome DevTools. Even the JS wasn't loaded in ripple (tested with a console.log). Have a good Day and thanks for your time!

Comment: No problem, please mark this question as solved. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the parse CDN was not found i.e . download the SDK and host it yourself instead

Answer (score 0):

Just run into the same issue. You are most likely missing the reference to parse.min.js.

The reference is typically in your index.html file, inside the header:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

        <! ---- LOOK HERE --------->
        <script src="js/parse.min.js"></script>
        <! ---- LOOK HERE --------->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/one.css" />
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```